# Insert data from two csv files in the database simultaneously using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv, insert

I have two csv files with me. I want to insert data from both these files for similar cells simultaneously in the database in a single table.
Example:
first.csv column names:**country, year, population(male)**
second.csv column names:**country, year, population(female)**

I want to insert data as: **country, year, population(male), population(female)** 
in the database. 
Thanks

Comment: So where's your code and what's the problem with it? Why do you have to do it simultaneously?

Comment: Actually 3 csv files of same type **population** are there with **male**, **female** and **total  population** in 3 different files. I don't want to create 3 different tables in the database but to combine all three in one single table **population**.That is why I want to insert simultaneously. Example:**INSERT INTO POPULATION VALUES(male(file1), female(file2), total(file3))**

Comment: What does simultaneity has to do with the number of tables you create?

Comment: Hint: absolutely nothing. And this still isn't a tutorial or code-writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the files have the same number of lines, something like this should work:

```
with open(filename1, 'rb') as f1, open(filename2, 'rb') as f2

  rdr1 = CsvReader(f1)
  rdr2 = CsvReader(f2)

  for file1_line in rdr1:

     file2_line = rdr2.next()

     # Perform your db query here
     # add the data in tables
```

Hope this helps.